# Clear image alignment with IText

Tags: pdf, itext

I add the image element (with alignment = left) in my document and then I add a little paragraph. Everything works good but now I need add another paragraph not aligned with image (I need add paragraph under the image and not on the right of image)

For example on html you can use style attribute: "clear:both".

Language is Visual Basic and last versione of iText

```
_image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(myimage)    
_image.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_LEFT + iTextSharp.text.Image.TEXTWRAP
_document.add(_image)
_document.add(New Paragraph("This text will be show on the right of the image"))
_document.add(New Paragraph("Also this text will be show on the right of the image but I want the text on the bottom of the image"))
```

you can see the this http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=53656

Somebody can help me?
Thanks to everybody

Comment: Please post the code that you tried and the version of iText/iTextSharp you are using. Also, see this chart for a list of CSS attributes that are currently supported in the XmlWorker: http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to create a `PdfPTable` and add cells in it. Add 2 cells in the first row and for the second row, give `colspan = 2`. Here is the sample code.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2); //table with 2 columns
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(_Image);
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Your text1"));
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Your text2"));
cell3.Colspan = 2;
Table.AddCell(cell1);
Table.AddCell(cell2);
Table.AddCell(cell3);
_document.Add(table);
```

**NOTE:***Always try including your content in table in a PDF as it generates a structured PDF.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, it's not my solution because sometime "text1" is very long and I want always wrap the image, but thank you anyway

Comment: ohh. i would have told you the solution if it was mentioned int the question properly. anyways check my edit tomorrow as i have the code in office.

Comment: @Saksham what is the better solution you said you would post? I don't see it here.

Comment: @Saksham did you ever get a answer for this?

Comment: @jpo this was answered way back and probably that was the last time I worked on iTextSharp. I have switched 2 companies after that and my technology as well. Sorry but I do not have answer. Will delete my comment